# How to get a version number from an output

Tags: powershell, batch-file

R&D has asked us to deploy a new outlook plugin to all the systems in the company... however, there is a catch. If you have any other plugins that are outdated from our company it will break them.. As such we need to determine if an endpoint has the plugin installed and what version it is. If its installed and less than version "X" then we need to update it. Another issue is that not everyone uses the plugins so we cant just push it to everyone and call it a day.

As such we found a query that will call WMI and spit out the output which we then write to a file. Running

```
"wmic product where "Vendor like '%Microsoft%'" get Name, Version > C:\temp\test.txt"
```

gives us output:

```
Name                                       Version  
First Plug-in for Microsoft Outlook      1.1.9.0  
Second Plug-in for Microsoft Outlook  2.0.2.0  
Third Plug-in for Microsoft Outlook    1.2.5.0  
etc.
```

What we want to do is to parse each one of those and write the version to a file so we can then see if we need to deploy the new plugin or not.

Ex:

```
First.txt contains 1.1.9.0
Second.txt contain 2.0.2.0
etc.
```

If for example Test.txt has no "First" in it don't make a file at all. We pretty much have to use batch file to do this but should be able to also do this with PowerShell (although that will take some tweaking as our deployment system isn't very powerful).

As such I was wondering if someone can point me in the right direction regarding how to do this on a Windows system.

Comment: A PowerShell solution of `gwmi win32_version -filter "name like '%Microsoft%'" | ?{ [version]$_.Version -lt [version]'2.0.2.0' } | %{ doUpgrade $_.Name }` might offer an easier path since PowerShell is capable of both performing the WMI query as well as casting the version values as version objects, allowing numeric comparison of major / minor / build / revision. You can eliminate the need for storing values in a file then later comparing them. The batch solution you seek could eventually leave you with ver 9.1.2.0 being greater than ver 10.0.1.0, because it is alphabetically so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**: This answer answers the question *as stated* and may be of interest from a regex-matching perspective, but *for a fundamentally better approach* see [rojo's comment on the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35906744/45375#comment-59475394).

---

The following Powershell pipeline writes to individual files, named for the product (with extension `.txt`) and containing the version number, as requested:

```
Get-Content C:\temp\test.txt | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object `
  { 
     if ($_ -match '^(.*[^ ]) +([^ ]+) *$') { 
       $fname = $matches[1] + '.txt'
       $ver = $matches[2]
       $ver > $fname 
     } 
  }
```

<sup>Note that the output files are written to the *current* directory.</sup>

- `Get-Content C:\temp\test.txt` sends the contents of the file line by line through the pipeline.
- `Select-Object -Skip 1` skips the header line.
- `$_ -match '^(.*[^ ]) +([^ ]+) *$'` matches the line at hand (`$_`) against a regular expression that uses capture groups (`(...)`) to capture the product name and the version number substrings, accessible through the elements of special match-info variable `$matches`.
- `$fname = $matches[1] + '.txt'` appends `.txt` to the 1st capture group - the product name - and stores it in variable `$fname`.
- `$ver = $matches[2]` saves the version number - the 2nd capture group - in variable `$ver`.
- `$ver > $fname` simply writes the version number to the output file.

  - Note that PowerShell creates UTF-16 LE-encoded files when you use output redirection (`>`); to use a different encoding, use, e.g., `$ver | Out-File -Encoding utf8`.

---

If you want to **call the entire PowerShell command from `cmd.exe` (a batch file)**, use the following:

```
powershell.exe -noprofile -command "Get-Content C:\temp\test.txt | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object { if ($_ -match '^(.*[^ ]) +([^ ]+) *$') { $fname = $matches[1] + '.txt'; $ver = $matches[2]; $ver > $fname } }"
```

---

To **only use the 2nd whitespace-separated token of the plug-in name** as the file name:

In both commands above, replace:

```
$fname = $matches[1] + '.txt'
```

with:

```
$fname = (-split $matches[1])[1] + '.txt'
```

Comment: That seems to work but do you guys know if its possible to do it via batch files (even if we have to split it into multiple files) as otherwise we will need to enable execution of scripts just to run this and then disable it (due to security requirements :\).

Comment: When I run this, I seem to get the following error:

Unexpected token '.1' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:136
+ Get-Content C:\temp\plugins.txt | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object { if
 ($_ -match '^(.*[^ ]) +([^ ]+) *$') { $fname = $matches.1 <<<<  + '.txt'; $ver
 = $matches.2; $ver > $fname } }
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (.1:String) [], ParentContainsError
   RecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Comment: @KonstantinV: On PowerShell <= v2, use `$matches[1]` instead of `$matches.1` and `$matches[2]` instead of `$matches.2` - I've also updated the answer.

Comment: I think we are getting closer as it does not error out anymore but it does not seem to make any files, also when I write the output to a file it does not seem to output anything as the file size is 0 MG. Again thank you for all the help I greatly appreciate it

Comment: As for not creating files: note that the command creates them in the _current_ directory - perhaps you're looking in the wrong place. The command as a whole has _no_ console output, so capturing its output is _expected to_ result in an empty file (`0` bytes).

Comment: Yep you are absolutely right... If I can ask one more question. Lets say my  plugs are called "google email plugin" "google encryption plugin" etc. is there a way for me to skip the first word and just collect the second word in the string making it the file name (basically I am trying to reduce the file name to just have the unique portion of the name and take out all the repeats).

Comment: @KonstantinV: See my update. Please try to state _all_ your requirements _up front_ next time.